Behavior of the number of components of disconnected reductive groups when intersecting a Levi subgroup
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $P=MN$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$ with its Levi decomposition ($N$ the unipotent radical, $M$ a Levi).
Let $H\subset M$ be a finite subgroup consisting of semisimple elements. Then we have two centralizers $C_M(H)$ and $C_G(H)$, namely the centralizer of $H$ in $M$ and in $G$ respectively, which are reductive by some general facts. They are not connected in general. We then have two component groups (the group of components) $\pi_0(C_M(H))$ and $\pi_0(C_G(H))$. I am wondering is there any relation between there orders $|\pi_0(C_M(H))|$ and $|\pi_0(C_G(H))|$?
Currently I am interested in a specific case: suppose $P=MN$ is a maximal parabolic subgroup of $G$, and the identity component $C_M(H)^\circ$ is just the connected center $Z(M)^\circ$ of $M$. Even in this case I have not yet found any concrete relation between these two orders.
Is there any useful fact/theorem related to this question? Thanks a lot in advance. (p.s. This question was motivated by the Langlands parameter in the local Langlands correspondence.)
